# How do I recognize shadowed crates in the rust documentation?

Tags: rust, documentation, rust-cargo

When I document my project by 'cargo doc' then it can happen that the name of my own project shadows a dependend crate which is then invisible.

So I do not see that a crate with the same name exists and this crate then keeps undocumented.

How can I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The best workaround is to just avoid this situation from the beginning. Just make sure you're not shadowing any public crates names. You can check on [crates.io](https://crates.io) if your desired name is available, if it's not I strongly recommend you choose a different name since if you ever want to publish it you'd have to rename it anyways.